# App resets imageview after restart

Tags: android, imageview

When I take an image and set it to imageview and then restart my app, imageview will be set to blank. What could the issue be?

Here is my code:

```
 private void initialize() {
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.breturnpic);
    ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btakepic);
    b = (Button) findViewById((R.id.bset));
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    ib.setOnClickListener(this);}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bset: {
            try {
                getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bmp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        case R.id.btakepic: {
            i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i, cameradata);
            break;}}}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);}}
```

Comment: If you want to show the image next time you launch the application, you need to store it either in sharedpreferences or in the db.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use the image picked on previous app sessions you should persist the data somehow. If is just an image you could save it in your device and keep a reference to the image's URI in your app's [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

You could also use your database to save these URI in a more structured fashion.